# find a Textview in ListActivity in android

Tags: android, listactivity

I'm usind ListActivity to show stock market information. Each row has my own layout with 4 textviews. I need to update the information of each stock as they change. 
My problem is I could extract a specific view from list, however I don't know how to find a textview within this view.The code below might clarify my problem.
This is what I've done which didn't work:

```
 ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
 View r =  list.getChildAt(2);
 TextView t =  (TextView) r.findViewById(R.id.t_buy);
 t.setText("3200$");
```

t_buy is one of the textviews in my layout. 
I was hopping that android has something like below, but it hasn't.

```
 TextView t =  (TextView) r.getChildAt(R.id.t_buy);
```

This is the screen shot of my app.

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create you custom adapter from BaseAdapter and override method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent)
{
    //...
    TextView textView;
    textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemText);
    textView.setText("some text");

}
```

see mode details here: http://codinglines.frankiv.me/post/14552677846/android-implementing-a-dynamically-loading-adapter

Answer (score 1):

You could try using getAdaper() on the list object and then use getItem() to retrieve the one you need.

Comment: could you explain it a little bit more or maybe make an example. thx

Comment: With getAdapter() you get the Adapter you used to populate the list. So you can cast to the actual type it is (if you used a custom one for instance). Once you have it calling getItem() with the desired position will return you the instance there, if used a SimpleCursorAdapter it will be the Cursor moved to that position. Once you have the object you can do what you need!

Answer (score 1):

You can update the items in adapter, and then invoke `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is best if you can use the **View getView** method because you are using a ListView and when you click on a List item you want to populate one of your custom layout with four TextViews as you have mentioned. This [links](http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/how-to-use-baseadapter-and-onitemclicklistener-in-android/) show you how to do it clearly.